# Export a git commit log to csv using short dates

Tags: git

Consider the command

```
git log --pretty=format:'"%h","%an","%aD","%s",' > log.csv
```

This works perfect, but I can't seem to figure out where to add the --date=short that is located within the [github documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

Comment: Did you try to use it before `git log`? Just like this: `git log --date=short --pretty=format:'"%h","%an","%aD","%s",' > log.csv`

Comment: Nope, and it worked perfectly! Thanks so much

Answer (score 4):

From [pretty-formats git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats), `%aD` is RFC822 style whereas `%ad` is the one that takes into account `--date= option` :

> '%ad': author date (format respects --date= option)
>
> '%aD': author date, RFC2822 style

```
git log --date=short --pretty=format:'"%h","%an","%ad","%s"' > log.csv
```